# Estoy intentando hacer que un switch sea case insensitive y no lo consigo

Tags: java, switch

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde el usuario debe introducir un día de la semana y el programa le dice si es fin de semana o no (he de hacerlo con un `switch`).

Como me parecía muy fácil he intentando añadirle algo de dificultad tratando de conseguir que el `switch` me acepte tanto "Lunes" como "lunes" o "LuNeS" y no lo consigo.

Este es el código del programa:

```
    String dia="";

    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce un día de la semana");

    dia=entrada.nextLine();

     switch (dia){

        case "Lunes":

        case "Martes":

        case "Miercoles":

        case "Jueves":

        case "Viernes":

            System.out.println(dia + " No es fin de semana");

            break;
        case "Sábado":

        case "Domingo":

            System.out.println(dia + " Es fin de semana");

        default: System.out.println("Introduce un día de la semana");

    }'''
```

Comment: Convierte a minúsculas el texto ingresado y lo comparas en el switch. Así te evitas de tener n combinaciones y comparaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar las los metodos `toLowerCase()` o `toUpperCase()` para convertir a `minúsculas` o `mayúsculas` respectivamente el día ingresado por teclado.
Para cambiar los caracteres con tilde puedes usar la Clase [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) y el método [`Replace`](https://rextester.com/KQGF27223)
Un pequeño error en tú código, te faltó escribir `break` después del último `case`

```
        String dia,convertir;
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un día de la semana");
        dia=entrada.nextLine();
        dia = Normalizer.normalize(dia , Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        dia = dia.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""); 
        convertir=dia.toLowerCase();   
        switch (convertir){

            case "lunes":
            case "martes":
            case "miercoles":
            case "jueves":
            case "viernes":
                System.out.println(convertir + " No es fin de semana");
                break;
            case "sabado":
            case "domingo":
                System.out.println(convertir + " Es fin de semana");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Día ingresado incorrecto!!");
        }
```

Comment: Y si escriben "`sábado`" o  "`miércoles`"?

Comment: @TomuRain, gracias por la pregunta; ya agregué el código corregido